# Better way to disable template argument deduction from a specific function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

Here is what I want to do:

```
template <typename T> void f(DisableDeduction<T> obj) {std::cout << obj;}
// Here DisableDeduction<T> aliases T, but in a such way
// that would prevent compiler from deducing T based
// on provided argument.

/* ... */

f<int>(1); // Works.
f(1); // Error, can't deduce template parameter based on argument.
```

This is how I currently achieve it:

```
template <typename T> struct DisableDeduction_Internal {using type = T;};
template <typename T> using DisableDeduction = typename DisableDeduction_Internal<T>::type;
```

It works perfectly (as described), but it introduces one extra helper type.

**But can I achieve same result without extra types?**

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<true, T>` ?

Comment: Since C++20, just use [`std::type_identity_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++20 you can use `std::type_identity_t<T>`.

Pre-C++20 I would suggest `std::enable_if_t<true, T>`.

`std::common_type_t<T>`, while seemingly innocuous, applies `std::decay` to the type, removing `const`, `volatile`, and/or reference-ness.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it by putting T in non deducible context (to the left of `::`), and use [std::common_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) from `<type_traits>`.

example:

```
template <typename T> void f(typename std::common_type<T>::type obj) {std::cout << obj;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll put that into a templated `using` (as before) for more convenient usage.

Comment: In C++14, `typename std::common_type<T>::type` can just be `std::common_type_t<T>` (which is shorter and more readable IMO).

Comment: More readable with a typedef, `template<typename T>
using no_infer = typename std::common_type<T>::type;`