# Casting char* to uint8_t* in a safe way in C++

Tags: c++

I have a (base) class with a virtual function that is supposed to return a pointer. There are two classes that derive from this class.

```
class A{
//...
    virtual uint8_t* getPointer(){

    }
}

class B: public A{
//...
    uint8_t* getPointer() override {
        return static_cast<uint8_t*>(myUnsignedChar);
    }
private:
    unsigned char* myUnsignedChar;
}


class C: public A{
//...
    uint8_t* getPointer() override {
        //return??
    }
private:
    char* myChar;
}
```

Class B has an `unsigned char*` so I can simply `static_cast` it to `uint8_t*`. However, class C has an `char*` and I cannot simply `static_cast` it to `uint8_t*`.

I have some questions:

since char isn't guaranteed to be 8 bits, then why the compiler does not complain of `static_cast<uint8_t*>(myUnsignedChar)`? If `char` in some architecture happens to be 16bit then how it is possible to cast to 8 bit integer?

I've noticed that `return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(frame.get()->data());` would work. I get that this is allowed because I'm simply telling C++ to read a pointer to a (possibly 8 bits data) as simply another thing. That is, if char is 8 bits, then all I'm going is reading those same 8 bits but imagining them as positive numbers. So it'll read -127 as 0 I guess, or something similar (depends on how negative numbers are represented in the architecture I guess).

So, how do I solve this problem? Looks like that `unsigned char*` to `uint8_t*` is only safe is `char` is 8 bits, and reinterpret_cast is only safe if `char` is 8 bits AND the data pointed by it is only composed of positive values.

What should I do?

Comment: While char isn't guaranteed to be 8 bits, it is almost always 8 bits anyways

Comment: @HackerBoss I guess it's safe to assume char is 8 bits in x86, x86_64 and armv7 and armv8a which are my target architectures, rigth? What about the possibility of the data pointed by char* being negative? Wouldn't interpreting it as uint8_t* cause problems?

Comment: For those architectures, you should be good to assume 2's-complement representation, in which case casting char to `uint8_t` should just cause those bits to be read differently. So negative values will become values in the range [128, 255]. Basically, the typical range of `signed char` is [-128, 127] and the typical range of `uint8_t` is [0, 255]

Comment: The compiler error messages pertain to your target architecture, not all possible architectures

Answer (score 4):

For this conversion, you can use a single `reinterpret_cast`, since it's a conversion between incompatible types between which there is no one-way implicit conversion, and no loss of qualifiers is involved.

```
return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(myChar);
```

The C-style cast notation could be used:

```
return (uint8_t *) myChar;
```

To guard against someone changing the type of `myChar` unexpectedly without thinking about the ramifications of the conversion, we can instead make it this:

```
return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(static_cast<char *>(myChar));
```

Now if `myChar` becomes `const char *`, the static cast will fail, and it will also fail if `myChar` becomes `int *`. In other words, we first `static_cast` the value to the type we already expect it to be, and then `reinterpret_cast` to the type we need it to be. The `reinterpret_cast` then works with an exact pair of types that is evident from this piece of code itself: it is plain to see that the input to it is a `char *`, and the output is `uint8_t *`.

If we need such casts often, we can make them more ergonomic like this, with  a template inline function:

```
// convert from F to T, without stripping qualifiers like const

template <typename T, typename F> inline T to_from_cast(const F &val)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<T>(static_cast<F>(val));
}
```

Now it's just:

```
return to_from_cast<uint8_t, char *>(myChar);
```

The C++ cast notation mimics the calling of template functions with explicit argument instantiation; therefore, we can write our own casts using such functions. When the type is violated, the compiler diagnostics won't be as nice, though.

And note that you can't use `to_from_cast` without specifying at least one template parameter; `T` can't be deduced because `T` doesn't appear in the function signature, only `F`. There is a downside here in that `to_from_cast<uint_8_t *>(myChar)` with only one template parameter is a valid expression.  `F` is deduced to whatever `myChar` is, oops! (But see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737487/better-way-to-disable-argument-based-template-parameter-deduction-for-functions) for how to suppress deduction for a template argument). An alternative with nicer diagnostics, and all type parameters required is, unfortunately, preprocessing:

```
#define to_from_cast(T, F, V) (reinterpret_cast<T>(static_cast<F>(V)))
```

> *since char isn't guaranteed to be 8 bits, then why the compiler does not complain of static_cast(myUnsignedChar)?*

If your `unsigned char` is 8 bits, then it's the same type as `uint8_t`; `uint8_t` is just a `typedef` alias for `unsigned char`.

On a system that has 9 bit bytes, you likely won't have a `uint8_t`; the availability of the exact-width types is implementation-defined.

Objects in C and C++ are measured in bytes. The character types like `char` and `unsigned char` have a size 1 by definition. No non-zero-sized object has a size smaller than 1.

If you have to write code which is portable to such systems, your code cannot assume that `uint8_t` exists.

Comment: Can you add a `const_cast` in the latter case?

Comment: But what about the possibilities that I talked? What if char is 16 bits? What if the data pointed by char is negative?

Comment: Oh, of course. But if you're giving out the address willy-nilly like this, changing it to const would probably have ripple effects all over the place.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs If `char` is 16 bits, then there can't be any type smaller than char. Remember, `sizeof(char) == 1`.  If you care about portability to a DSP chip like that or whatever, then don't rely on `uint8_t` existing.

Comment: @Barmar We could make it `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<char *>(myChar))`.  This is actually an interesting possibility because although it will fail us by not detecting that `myChar` has changed to `const char *`, it guards against type changes in `myChar`; the `const_cast` will fail if `myChar` changes to `int *`.  A better way for that would be to use `static_cast` in place of the `const_cast`.